# Why doesn't this code involving a ListView, an ArrayAdapter and a view holder work as expected?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to make a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter<T>` where the type `T` has a second use as a view holder. This may seem a bit strange but the idea behind this is that I can then write an `onClick(View view)` method which starts with the line `view.getTag()` taking you straight to the instance of `T` that the `View` was created from.

Here is the code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final class ViewHolder {

        private final String string;
        private TextView textView;

        private ViewHolder(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        final List<ViewHolder> viewHolders = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            viewHolders.add(new ViewHolder("A"));
            viewHolders.add(new ViewHolder("B"));
            viewHolders.add(new ViewHolder("C"));
        }
        final ArrayAdapter<ViewHolder> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewHolder>(this, -1, viewHolders) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view;
                TextView textView;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
                    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
                } else {
                    view = convertView;
                    textView = ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).textView;
                }
                ViewHolder viewHolder = viewHolders.get(position);
                textView.setText(viewHolder.string);
                viewHolder.textView = textView;
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
                return view;
            }
        };
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view)).setAdapter(adapter);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Collections.rotate(viewHolders, 1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work. In both cases (`convertView` is or is not `null`) you're always returning a `View` containing a `TextView` where the text has been set to `viewHolders.get(position).string`. So surely despite the complexity of this approach you should always see `A`, `B`, `C`, `A`, `B`, `C`, etc? There are 60 different instances of `ViewHolder` and you should never have the same `TextView` in two places on screen because the `convertView` you get passed should come from an off-screen position? I'm plainly wrong as after clicking rotate a few times the order can get messed up. I'd be really grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Here is `activity_my.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Rotate"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `item_layout.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that Collections.rotate behaves the way that you expect? I'd write a small, one-off class (or a JUnit test) to confirm that after a certain number of rotations, the list has the order that you expect. If it does, then look elsewhere, but not before.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing, but I think I've figured out how this can happen.

- Step 1: `getView` is invoked for the `ViewHolder` `h` and `View` `v` is returned.

Now `v.getTag() == h` and `h.textView` is the `TextView` in `v`.

- Step 2: `getView` is invoked for the same `ViewHolder` `h`, but this time a different `View` `w` is returned.

At this point `w.getTag() == h` and `h.textView` is changed to the `TextView` in `w`.

- Step 3: `getView` is called and the `convertView` used is `v`.

At this point `v.getTag()` is still `h` from step 1, but `h.textView` was changed to the `TextView` in `w` in Step 2. This means that the line `textView.setText(viewHolder.string);` is not actually setting the text in the correct `TextView`.